# Add Child View Controller with non-opaque background

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to add a view controller, initialised with a xib file to the child view controllers property of a controller.

```
self.categoryViewController = [[CategoryPickerViewController alloc] init];

[self addChildViewController:self.categoryViewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.categoryViewController animated:NO];
```

However when the view is pushed it expands in both width and height even though I have specifically set the dimensions of the view in interface builder.

This results in my view being shown on a black background.

[image]

Are there any specific options to ensure that the loaded view maintains the dimensions set in IB and ensures a see-through background.

The height is set to 360 but when I log frame.size.height it appears as 504

Comment: Why would you call both `addChildViewController:` and `pushViewController:` on the same view controller? Do one or the other based on your needs.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to add a controller as a child and then push it with the navigation controller. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is probably my mistake from following other people's code. I'm simply trying to show my custom view as a 'pop up' style on top of the original view. Using just addChildViewController does not push the view on screen, and pushViewController has the same effect as with both

Comment: Then put your view controller in its own navigation controller and present it instead of pushing it. This will make it slide up from the bottom. Either way, do not call `addChildViewController`.

Comment: Thanks maddy, If I was to do this though would I still be able to see the original content under the parts of the screen the view isn't occupying?

Comment: No, the presented view controller would fill the screen. If you want to display a view controller that only covers part of the screen then you are on your own for displaying the view controller.

Comment: FYI - when you want to respond to someone specific, use their full username preceded by the `@` sign. Otherwise there is no notification.

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.categoryViewController = [[CategoryPickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryViewController"]`

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks Winston, however this provides the same results as before

Comment: maddy, thanks for the comment. I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom view controller transition, which isn't too terrible in iOS 7. All of the standard, out-of-the-box stuff you can do in iOS will not allow you to properly present a view controller with transparency or without consuming the entire view (on iPhone).

I suggest checking out http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html or http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/ for examples of how to do custom transitions.